# C# UnauthorizedAccessException error

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I am transfering files through sockets. When I try to save files to a custom directory, I get this error using BinaryWrite function.

```
private void downloadFromServer()
{
   try
   {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[5000 * 1024];
      byte[] incomingFile = new byte[5000 * 1024];
      buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(getUserName.Text + "Download" 
         + getFileName.Text + "end");
      clientSocket.Send(buffer);
      activityLog.AppendText("Preparing to download... \n");
      while (incomingFile != null)
      {
         clientSocket.Receive(incomingFile);

         int receivedBytesLen = incomingFile.Length;
         int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(incomingFile, 0);
         File.WriteAllBytes(fileDir, incomingFile);
      } 
      activityLog.AppendText("File saved to " + fileDir + "\n");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: You sure you have access to the fileDir directory?

Comment: I am sure but how can I check it?

Comment: I tried to save to a file through C:\\ and my second disk E:\\ both failed with same error

Comment: User, who launch the program, should have "write" permissions on target directory.

Comment: How can I check that ? I looked properties through vs and users have  all the accesses reading writing ect... Still no solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File.WriteAllBytes(fileDir, incomingFile);` requires file name. From variable name it looks like you are using folder name. I.e. should be `@"e:\tempfile.bin"` instead of `@"e:\"`.

[File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Given a byte array and a **file path**, this method opens the specified file, writes the contents of the byte array to the file, and then closes the file.

Note if `fileDir` means file name than you should looks for other not-so-truthful names throughout your code...